# Using akka-http with Play 2.5, how do I customize "Illegal request-target"

Tags: scala, playframework, akka-http

I am getting

```
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
< Content-Length: 96

Illegal request-target: Invalid input '\', expected pchar, '/', '?' or 'EOI' (line 1, column 17)
```

for URLs containing `\`, which is ok, I'd like to have 400 going forward, but I want to change the message, so it's more user-friendly.

Seems like it happens before it gets into any of controllers.

p.s. I know there is `akka.http.parsing.uri-parsing-mode = relaxed`, but I don't want to do it (different message is what I want:).

Update:
sample URLs causing `Illegal request-target` are:

```
http://host.host/hello\world
http://host.host/hello{all
http://host.host/hello"all
```

and so on

Comment: Looks like an open issue: https://github.com/akka/akka-http/issues/210